# Remove all python configurations from Mac

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to use Python for a programming project for a class and from other courses I have different versions of Python installed and through different ways (brew, Python's web page...), i.e., I have them installed in different locations. This is giving me a lot of trouble, due to environment configurations and whatnot. Also, I kind of want to clean up my laptop from this mess.

I want to have a fresh start with Python (and all that comes with it: numpy, etc) so that I have just ONE Python version that serves all the Python programs that I need to build.

How can I find and remove all Python versions from my Mac (Sonoma 14.0, M1) safely? (I read somewhere that macOS uses some Python configurations internally and that I shouldn't mess with those).

Comment: "that I have just ONE Python version that serves to all the Python programs that I need to build" is the wrong approach. [You'll want a Python virtualenv per project.](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)

Comment: Or use docker ;)

as of removing them. I think the executables are in /usr/local/bin/python so you'll know which ones are installed

Keep 2,7 as that is used by MacOS (please check with your specific MacOS version.

after this you can remove the files from you /Library/Framworks and /Applications folder.

Comment: You might also want to cleanup your PATH btw

Comment: There are many, many ways Python could have been installed on the system, I don't think it's realistic to expect us to be able to post an exhaustive answer which solves this scenario for all of them. Removing Python installations is not particularly useful for your use case anyway. Just decide on a version and make sure it's early in your `PATH` and use that, or use an explicit path to wherever it's installed (i.e. `/usr/local/bin/python3.9` or whatever). As suggested by AKX, probably use a virtual environment to strip off any packages you may have inadvertently installed system-wide.

Comment: @GijsBeijer Modern MacOS does not use Python 2.7 any longer. Since I think a couple versions back, `/usr/bin/python3` is the only Python provided by the OS (in my case, on Sonoma, it's 3.9.6)

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for clarifying this, That is why I added the suggestion to check it with the specific MacOS version ;) 

Havent used Mac for some time now